# Blob Storage - handle files directly on it

Tags: c#, .net, azure, asp.net-core, blobstorage

I desire an efficient solution to iterate through large files located on blob storage in C#. I want to use the blob storage as a local storage. In my research I've only found solutions where the file has to be downloaded or streamed.

Is it possible to directly iterate through a file on blob storage without downloading it locally or to a stream?

Comment: Azure Function?

Comment: So what exactly do you need to do with those files? Can't you process them using an azure service so you do not need to transfer the data outside the azure region? AKA bring the compute to where the data lives.

Comment: Use a cloud service or no. It's like asking can I search my friends bag in some other country, no you can't.... however If you had a process or friend that is closer you wouldn't have to transit the contents to inspect it. Short story is azure isn't magic,

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to directly iterate through a file on blob storage without downloading it locally or to a stream?

Simple answer: No. You can list the blobs, i.e. their properties. But if you want to actually work with the content, you need to download it from the storage account. The storage is a pure object store.

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned, this is not possible. Maybe you could split up your files into smaller chunks and up-/downoad these for manipulations. If for example you have a 1MB file, split it up into 10 KB chunks and add an integer suffix to your original name to distinct the individual chunks. If you need a specific part of the file, calculate the needed chunk ids and download these files only.

If this approach works for you, highly depends on your data. Can it be split by size or some other criteria (e.g. number of lines, json elements), does changing the data within one chunk have impact on other chunks (e.g. split by rows and you insert a row into a chunk). So be careful with this approach and choose wisely.

Comment: Oliver, thanks for your answer. The files go up to 10GB. Also, it's not convenient to split the file into parts and pass it onto a library, cause that library should iterate through the file. The input of this method is either a file or a Stream. I am searching for the optimal way, memory-wise.

Comment: If the input of your method is a stream, you could create your own derived stream class that loads the split up chunks when requested. The real deal breaker is, must the file be updated or is it a read-only process?

Comment: It it a read-only process.

Comment: I am trying not to load a lot of data in the RAM, cause this should be working with multiple big files at once.

Comment: The C# BlobClient has a `DownloadStreamingAsync()` method. It returns a stream and also takes a range parameter if you only want a subset of the file. Doesn't that match your needs?

Comment: But I think it's not smart to split the file, since it's best to iterate directly in the whole file without loading it neither in RAM nor locally. So if this isn't possible with BlobStorage, do you have an idea of any other service with which this would be possible?

Comment: Sorry, never had this issue. But I think I would stick to the blob storage and create my own derived stream class that uses the the mentioned blob streaming method to download the requested portions and throws away *old* chunks.

Answer (score -1):

I have not tried it but I would try using a file share to store the large files. Then create a docker image with your processing code and push it to azure container registry. Then create a container instance using this image and you can mount the file share to that container instance. Azure container instances are only billed for the duration they are running. Using the SDK you start a container instance whenever you need to process the large file.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).